# Accessing Multiple Replicated Schemas in a Single SQL query?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, connection-string

There are 5 replica's of an Oracle database in widely separated geographical locations. One important table has a 'last update timestamp' column, recording the last time a row in that table received an update (The table receives many updates per second).
I want to make a single query that when run outputs the largest time interval of the most recent "last update timestamp" from the current time.
Today, I am manually running independent queries like
select max(UpdateTimestamp) from tableName;
from 5 tabs in SQL Developer, 1 tab for each connection, and manually looking for delayed updates.  The password is the same for all, but the connection string is a little different to access each instance.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are there database links between the various databases?  A lot of approaches to replication would require database links to be in place but not all approaches.  If there aren't database links today, can you create database links between each instance?

Comment: I cannot add links.  Some of the replication is Golden Gate.

Comment: If you don't have database links and you can't add database links then you probably can't do this with a single query.  You could write some code that made 5 different connections, issued 5 different queries, and automated the comparison.  But you're stuck with separate connections and separate queries.